# Explain _ Information: You may need to update /etc/fstab

Tags: linux, ubuntu, partitioning, mount, kubuntu

with

```
neofetch --stdout |grep 'OS:'
OS: Kubuntu 22.04.3 LTS x86_64
```

To re-purpose a drive ...
this drive was made raw by:

- deleting all files
- deleting all partitions by
- using badblocks command
- writing ones (1s) to drive via a badblocks command.

.

To re-purpose drive, the first command was, make a Partition Table:
`sudo parted --align opt /dev/sd_ mktable msdos`
sd_ = sda

message1:
`Information: You may need to update /etc/fstab.`

With respect to `Kubuntu 22.04.3` what does message1 mean?

Does message1 mean:

- Ignore message1, keep going, partition disk, format ...?
- run `sync` command ?
- Restart computer ?
- Shut down computer ?
- other actions?

.

a search engine found this ...
message1:
`Information: You may need to update /etc/fstab.`

It is a message that normally appears in several
partition editors when you create a new partition,
it is to let you know that
if you want it to be mounted on boot it needs to be
added as an entry to
/etc/fstab like so:

```
[Identifier] [Mount point] [FS Type] [Mount Opts] [Dump] [FSCK Check order]  
LABEL=t-home2   /home      ext4    defaults,auto_da_alloc 0  2
```

.

message1:
`Information: You may need to update /etc/fstab.`

With respect to `Kubuntu 22.04.3` what does above message1 mean?

--

Comment: Hello Frank, FYI  /etc/fstab is dated months ago, May 2023, when iso installed, 
thus No recent system changes by Kubuntu and 
No manual changes by me.  
/etc/fstab has two (2) entries SWAP + ext4.  But today 
```lsblk -ae7 -oType,name,path,size,fsuse%,tran,pttype,fstype,label,partlabel,mountpoints |wc -l```
shows 15 entries (6 disks + 9 Partitions) and today 
/etc/fstab only has two (2) entries.  Something else is going on.  
For today i ignored ```Information: You may need to update /etc/fstab.``` 
until new details are posted.

Comment: "if you need help with a problem, you should probably tell us what it is." 
To re-purpose drive, the first command was, make a Partition Table:  
```sudo parted --align opt /dev/sd_ mktable msdos```   sd_ = sda --- 
message1:   ```Information: You may need to update /etc/fstab.```   
"a problem"  With respect to ```Kubuntu 22.04.3``` what does above message1 mean?  
Said differently, what action to do? with 
message1:   ```Information: You may need to update /etc/fstab.```

Comment: Just look at the file and make sure its still configured the way you need it to be. that's all. if mount points, or options, or disk device names (/dev/sda), or UUIDs, or whatever else have changed then you may want to update the file to meet your new needs. about the only reason you might NEED to adjust the file would be if your boot partition had changed in some way (as then you wouldn't be able to boot unless you fix it). its not telling you that you MUST update the file, or saying that its changed the file, or anything else other than "look it over and see if this is still what you want".

Comment: for future readers ... 
"look it over (/etc/fstab) and see if this is still what you want" 
and for my computer with ```Kubuntu 22.04.3``` i ignored the message 
```Information: You may need to update /etc/fstab.``` and 
no changes to ```/etc/fstab``` and 
computer seems to be working fine for now.  
But we know -- the map is not the territory.  
This means the paper map we look at and 
we make plans with has little to do with the land we travel -- 
the bumps the swamps and mountains...

Comment: So, is this solved? If so, post an answer, not a comment, indicating the solution.

Comment: On August 09 2023, Post made / uploaded to superuser site.  
On August 21 2023, music2myear said ```"So, is this solved?"``` 
On August 25 2023, ```4``` days later, music2myear question arrived by email.  
Question = ```"So, is this solved?"``` Answer = ```No.```

Answer (score 0):

"Information: You may need to update /etc/fstab." is just something `parted` prints out of turn: it's not like it knows whether or not you should actually update `fstab`.

You can safely ignore the warning (and I'd say that, shall you wish to, you could also pester the parted devs to remove this confusing message).